# How do I connect to Hyper-V server with SCVMM Admin Console?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have Hyper-V server installed and running on a domain. On the same domain, I have a Win2k8 machine that has SCVMM admin console installed. When I try to connect to my other machine via IP address, I get a message that says "Unable to connect to the Virtual Machine Manager server xx.xxx.xxx.xxx. The virtual Machine Manager service on that server did not respond."

I have enabled all remote management settings on the Hyper-V server. I have tried changing the firewall settings as stated: [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/russel/archive/2008/10/22/configuring-hyper-v-server-for-remote-management.aspx) but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install the SCVMM agent on the Hyper-V box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the SCVMM agent installed on any Hyper-V box you want to manage. The SCVMM can push the Hyper-V agent out to the other servers.

Go to Hosts > Add Host and enter all the details for the server it. It should then try to push the SCVMM Agent out to that server and add it to your Hosts list.